# All possible combinations of all possible length

Tags: c++, combinatorics

All possible combinations of all possible length

I have array like this. It can have arbitrary length rows and cols, however, cols length is fixed for every row.

```
{
    {a, b},
    {c, d},
    {e, f}
}
```

And i need all possible combinations with all possible length.

All combinations, example for array above:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f

ac, ad, ae, af, bc, bd, be, bf, ce, cf, de, df

ace, acf, ade, adf, bce, bcf, bde, bdf
```

**How do i accomplish this?** 
Algorithm description will be enough, however, code example (preferably C++) will help me a lot. I understand there is `recursion` smell with `for` loops, but i can't do it properly.

Comment: "i can't do it properly." why? what did you try?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 it is not same question. I was asked for editing, but question was blocked.

Comment: You want the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (where you have empty element)

Comment: Use recursive function calls. If you cannot get something to work with that, *that* is when you should ask a question.

Comment: You say "all possible lengths" but your example omits length zero.  There will always be one possible length zero output.  If you only want lengths >= 1 then say so explicitly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Algorithm all combinations all lengths", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  A shorter term is "power set".  This problem is covered *quite* well on line, with a variety of completed solutions.  We expect you to do this research before posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed by levels as your formatted output in description.

- For the first level, you will have your characters
- Second level you do a cartesian product between each pair of adjacent rows (easy 2 for loops)
- Third level : for each result in second level, do a cartesian product with the row following the 2 adjacent rows

and so on.. until level N where N is the number of rows

Answer (score -1):

An algorithm for your example is:

```
function rec(str, array, level)
    if level = array.size()
        print str
    else
        for i in append(array[level], "")
            rec(concat(str, i), array, level + 1)
        endfor
    endif
```

You would start with

```
rec("", {{a, b},{c, d},{e, f}}, 0)
```